# How to use pointers to the vector in STL like we assign pointers to a array while passing address of array to another function?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, arguments, function-call

In case of array --->

```
 void displayu(int * p){
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
         cout<<p[I];
        }
 }
main(){
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
displayu(arr);
}
```

In the case of vectors in STL-->

```
void displayu(vector <int> * p){
    for (int i = 0; i < p->size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<p[i];
    }
    
}
main(){
     vector <int> nums{0,2,1,5,3,4};
//I tried to do this ;) 
     displayu(nums);
}
//it is giving me an error .
```

Another way I tried to solve this problem -->

```
void displayu(vector <int> * p){
    vector <int> :: iterator Itr = p->begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < p->size(); i++)
    {
      cout<<Itr[i];
    }
    
}

int main(){
     vector <int> nums{0,2,1,5,3,4};
//I tried to do this ;) 
     displayu(nums);
}
```

The second and third method gives me an error but intuitively I think this is right like passing nums should pass the address of the first element in vector nums. Am I right about this passing of vector by Its name(the way we do it in array)?
Is there any quality improvement in my problem or any other better method? If there is a better method please suggest me.
Also, it will be great if you can explain me the part I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have to dereference the pointer before you an apply the `[]` operator. `cout<<(*p)[i];` is probably the easiest , most readable direct solution, but I'd  work around with a reference rather than a pointer. `void displayu(vector <int> & p)`.

Comment: `displayu(&nums)` will pass the address of `nums` but there are a lot of issues w the rest of the code... e.g. `p[i]` should be `p->at(i)`, etc,,,

Answer (score 1):

You declared the function as having one parameter that is a pointer to a vector

```
void displayu(vector <int> * p){
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you are calling the function passing an object of the vector type instead of a pointer to the vector.

```
displayu(nums);
```

At least you should call the function like

```
displayu( &nums);
```

Though it is unclear why the function parameter has the pointer type.

Declare and define the function for example like

```
void displayu( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

or

```
void displayu( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

and call it like

```
displayu(nums);
```

The difference between an object of an array type and an object of the container type vector is that array designators used in expressions as for example as an argument expression if the corresponding parameter is not a referenced type with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. Vectors do not have such an implicit conversion.